# Marketo removes token from style definition

Tags: html, marketo

I am trying to use a token value in a style tag in Marketo. For example:

```
<tr style="{{my.token_style}}">...</tr>
```

I do this in the "HTML Source Editor" for a section of an email. When I save everything and re-open the email, my changes are gone. To test, I added another bit to the style:

```
<tr style="x-test:0; {{my.token_style}}">...</tr>
```

When I saved this and re-opened the email, my token part had been stripped out:

```
<tr style="x-test:0;">...</tr>
```

Is it possible to use tokens in style? Is there a better way to edit the raw HTML content of a section that will prevent Marketo from stripping out the tokens from within the style definition?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to use `Email Actions > HTML Tools > Replace HTML`. This isn't a great solution, but it works. I'd be interested to see if there is a better option, though.